# http 500 calling apex method imperatively with complex parameter

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to call an Apex method imperatively with complex parameters from a Lightning Web Component but I'm getting an http 500 response every time. Here is what I'm doing which is a copy of [this](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams/apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams.js) recipe.

So I have a TestController with an action exposed and a couple of inner classes which are my request/response objects:

```
 public with sharing class TestController {
    public TestController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static TestResponse testAction(TestRequest req){
        return new TestResponse(req);
    }

    public class TestResponse {
        @AuraEnabled public String testId {get; set;}

        public TestResponse(TestRequest req){
            this.testId = req.testId;
        }
    }

    public class TestRequest { 
        @AuraEnabled public String testId {get; set;}
    }
}
```

The javascript code for the lwc is:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
import testAction from "@salesforce/apex/TestController.testAction";

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    @track res;

   goToServer(){
        const request = { testId: "foo" };
        testAction({ req: request })
              .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                  console.log(error);
              });
    }
}
```

And this is the response I always get from the server:

```
{
   statusText: "Server Error",
   ok: false,
   status: 500,
   body: {
   message: "An internal server error has occurred↵Error ID: 214808163- 
 50404 (1739684013)"
   },
   headers: {}
}
```

It seems to be a problem when salesforce it's trying to bind what it's being sent from the client to the parameter object because it doesn't even reach the controller action.

**UPDATE**
I am working on a scratch org, and have the component in a lightning community

Comment: Do your apex debug logs give you any error message?

Comment: nothing @Kasper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem looks like the combination of **both** Apex inner classes and a namespace.

- With neither, a class name is e.g. `MyOuter`
- With an inner class, a class name is e.g. `MyOuter.MyInner`
- With a namespace, a class name is e.g. `myNs.MyOuter`
- With both, a class name is e.g. `myNs.MyOuter.MyInner`

The **both** case - two dots - appears to be broken. So the workaround is to not use inner classes.

(Daniel is a colleague of mine.)

Comment: It took far too long to find this answer on google.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and all work fine. It's very strange for me. Looks like problem with server connection. Try to deploy again your code.

Comment: I'm deploying to a scratch org through sfdx force:source:push. Could it be something with the org definition?

Comment: I have done it on scratch org - it is all right too.

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps having a namespace set in the scratch org is the problem?

Comment: Alexandr, Did you test in a Community or a normal UI page?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Alexandr. I have seen this issue come up when there is an issue with my Apex Controller that my LWC references. Try re-deploying your Apex Controller and LWC to confirm everything can push successfully. In my case, the params changed on another Apex Class that my Apex Controller was calling, and I didn't realize it until my Apex Controller failed to deploy. My error message was slightly different:

`Error: apex://Apex_Controller_Name: No apex action available for Apex_Controller_Name.methodName↵`

`Internal Error: 500`

Answer (score 0):

Probably namespace.
The only solution I found was to recieve the param as Object,
then serialize it to Json and deserialize it using the inner class type.